# Parallel Invocation of service methods

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, plinq

I have made one WCF service Method which is consuming third party service methods(call `methodA`, `methodB`, `methodC`) and here all three belongs to different services i.e. `serviceA`, `serviceB`, `serviceC`.

Each method accepting single input object for processing (not List of input object). but I have to work on multiple objects, so I am consuming this methods in for loop.

Now the problem is, suppose I have 3 objects to process with `methodA`, 2 objects to process with `methodB` and  5 objects to process with `methodC` and consider each method taking 1 sec to process then total time taken to process all is almost 10 seconds. To overcome this problem after googling I got options like threading and parallel-linq. of course I don't have enough knowledge about threading and its performance, I choose to stay away. Now with parallel linq I found performance is up. But still expectations are not satisfied (and sometime its throwing timeout exception).
So please advice what should i try now? whether to dive in threading or anything other to try?

Comment: take a look at `Task Parallel Library`.

Comment: i would say that `Parallel.Invoke` is what you need. You code will be `Parallel.Invoke(()=>ServiceA.methodA(param1), ()=>Serviceb.methodB(param2), ()=>ServiceC.methodC(param3));`

Comment: And personally i don't understand what you mean with this `suppose i have 3 objects to process with methodA, 2 objects to process with methodB and 5 objects to process with methodC`. Maybe post your code ?

Comment: Does the caller of the original service operation need a response within a certain time? Do they need a response at all?

Answer (score 1):

As [`TPL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) in general or Parallel class are solutions too, I suggest you to try out the [`TPL Dataflow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx) library as you have a data flowing across your application, and your code will be much more structured this way.

So you can create 3 [`ActionBlock<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684.aspx) objects, each for the services you have, and post data to them in your loop. Also you can add task continuation handler for them so you'll be notified then all of messages are consumed by the services. Also you can add a [`BufferBlock<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160414.aspx) and [link it to other ones](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228604.aspx) with filter function. The code will be something like this:

```
void ProducingMethod()
{
    var serviceABlock = new ActionBlock<YourInputObject>(o =>
    {
        serviceA.Call(o);
    });
    serviceABlock.Completion.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        sendNotifyA();
    });

    var serviceBBlock = new ActionBlock<YourInputObject>(o =>
    {
        serviceB.Call(o);
    });
    serviceBBlock.Completion.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        sendNotifyB();
    });

    var serviceCBlock = new ActionBlock<YourInputObject>(o =>
    {
        serviceC.Call(o);
    });
    serviceCBlock.Completion.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        sendNotifyC();
    });

    foreach (var objectToProcess in queue)
    {
        if (SendToA)
        {
            serviceABlock.SendAsync(objectToProcess);
        }
        else if (SendToB)
        {
            serviceBBlock.SendAsync(objectToProcess);
        }
        else if (SendToC)
        {
            serviceCBlock.SendAsync(objectToProcess);
        }
    }
}
```